# How to install SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint

I heard that SharePoint Server 2016 has been released.
How can I install new SharePoint server 2016?
does anyone has a reference?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2016 is only in technical preview at the moment. If you're determined you can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48712). I ***would not*** deploy this on any production systems. This is purely for review and is not yet in a release state.